# MDX: dynamic named set on cubes calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a dynamic named set that can be used in slicing data using date dimension. I want to have a several named set something like last day, last 7 days, last month, last quarter and so on. For "last day" named set, i am thinking of doing something like.

```
StrToMember("[Date].[Calendar].[Day].&[" + DateAdd("d", -1,Tail( [Date].[Calendar].[Day], 1) + "]")
```

I want `DateAdd("d", -1, Tail( [Date].[Calendar].[Day], 1) + "]")` to return the member_value so that i can build the uniquename string to return a member, is it possible?

The reason why I am using `DateAdd` is that, sometimes I am having a gap in my data for Day level, so using previousmember will sometimes return a wrong data.

Ps: What I meant for the last day is not actually equal to function `Now()-1`, it is the last day that is available in the cube, that is why I cannot depend on the servers system time to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will hopefully give you the last day:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[LastDay] AS
 Tail([Date].[Calendar].[Day]).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)
SET [VariousDates] AS
 {[Date].[Calendar].[LastDay]}
SELECT
 [VariousDates] ON 0
FROM [MyCube]
```

You can then create more members in the set `[VariousDates]`:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[LastDay] AS
 Tail([Date].[Calendar].[Day]).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)
MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[Last7Days] AS
 AGGREGATE(
    Tail(
      [Date].[Calendar].[Day]
      ,7
    )
  )
SET [VariousDates] AS
 { 
   [Date].[Calendar].[LastDay]
  ,[Date].[Calendar].[Last7Days]
  }
SELECT
 [VariousDates] ON 0
FROM [MyCube]
```

(above not tested but hopefully helps)

Comment: Thanks! I just want to ask regarding the ITEM() function? Why did you use it twice?

Comment: Tail returns a set of tuples. The first ITEM(0) then returns the first tuple from that set. The second ITEM(0) returns the first member of the tuple. We're then guaranteed a member so `WITH MEMBER` won't get confused. In this example `TAIL` is used without a second argument so is just returning a single tuple so you'd probably get away with just one ITEM(0)?